# Html table + JSON response + select box

Tags: jquery, html, json

Below is my select box

```
<select id="ProductCode" style="border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;" name="ProductCode">
   <option value="1">Product Description 1 - Box</option>
   <option value="2">Product Description 2 - Carton</option>
   <option value="3">Product Description 3 - Bottle</option>
   <option value="4">Product Description 4 - Cylinder</option>
</select>
```

I have a table and I need to populate it with JSON response
Below is the Json

```
[{"RQST_KEY":"1844","EFT_RQST_ID":"1845","EFT_CODE":null,"EFT_DATE":"14-JAN-14","EXPECTED_DATE":"07-JAN-14","EFT_REQUESTOR":"Tecnics2","EFT_STATUS":"NEW","EFT_SUPPLIER":"Tecnics2","DELIVERY_LOCN":"1","REMARKS":"kk","APPROVE_FLAG":null,"LINE_NUMBER":"1846","PRODUCT_CODE":"2","UOM":null,"ORDER_QTY":"90"}]
```

All is fine, I can get the value of Product Code from JSON which is "2", this is second option in my select box. If I insert this into my table's  obviously it will show as "2", but I need to insert the text "Product Description 2 - Carton" into the table cell.

JS

```
for (var i=0; i<result.length ;i++) {

                html += '<tr id="tr-'+tblcounter+'"><td>'
                           + result[i].PRODUCT_CODE
                           + '</td><td class="class1">'
                           + result[i].ORDER_QTY
                           + '</td><td><a href="#" onClick="editRow(this);"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/edit_icon.jpg" height="20px" width="20px"></a>'
                           + '</td><td><a href="#" onClick="deleteRow(this);"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/delete_icon.jpg" height="16px" width="16px"></a>'
                           + '</td></tr>';
                   tblcounter++;
              }

              $('#rqstLines').append(html);
```

result is the response of AJAX call. So how to insert the option text into td from JSON response. Thanks

Comment: is it possible that you can hardcode 
"Product Description +result[i].PRODUCT_CODE+ - Carton". otherwise other approach needs to be searched.

Answer (score 1):

you would get the text from your select box by value like so:

```
$("#ProductCode option[value=2]").text();
```

so your final code would look like this:

```
var selectValue = $("#ProductCode option[value=" + result[i].PRODUCT_CODE + "]").text();
html += '<tr id="tr-'+tblcounter+'"><td>'
           + selectValue 
           + '</td><td class="class1">'
           + result[i].ORDER_QTY
           + '</td><td><a href="#" onClick="editRow(this);"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/edit_icon.jpg" height="20px" width="20px"></a>'
           + '</td><td><a href="#" onClick="deleteRow(this);"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/delete_icon.jpg" height="16px" width="16px"></a>'
           + '</td></tr>';
```

UPDATE: [Fiddle Added to prove out code concept](http://jsfiddle.net/RX4EZ/3/)

Comment: It is returning empty string as option value

Comment: my jquery version is 1.7.2

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RX4EZ/3/  type the number into the box that you want to see the value for.  this is showing that if you pass the right number, it will return the right value